# How can I find the determinant of a $n\times n$ square matrix whose all diagonal elements are equal to $a$ and off-diagonal elements are equal to $b$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

How can I find the determinant of this type of square matrix of $n\times n$ $$\begin{vmatrix} a&b&b&b& \ldots&b\\b&a&b&b&\ldots&b\\b&b&a&b&\ldots&b \\ \vdots&b&b&a&\ldots &b \\ b&b&b&\ldots &a&b \\b&b&b&b&\ldots &a \end{vmatrix}_{n\times n}=?$$

I have applied elementary operation: $C_1\to C_1+C_2+C_3+\ldots+C_n$
$$\begin{vmatrix} a+(n-1)b&b&b&b& \ldots&b\\a+(n-1)b&a&b&b&\ldots&b\\a+(n-1)b&b&a&b&\ldots&b \\ \vdots&b&b&a&\ldots &b \\ a+(n-1)b&b&b&\ldots &a&b \\a+(n-1)b&b&b&b&\ldots &a \end{vmatrix}_{n\times n}$$
Applied, $C_2\to C_2-C_3$, $C_3\to C_3-C_4$, $\ldots$, $C_{n-1}\to C_{n-1}-C_n$
$$=(a+(n-1)b)\begin{vmatrix} 1&0&0&0& \ldots&b\\1&a-b&0&0&\ldots&b\\1&0&a-b&0&\ldots&b \\ \vdots&0&0&a-b&\ldots &b \\ 1&0&0&\ldots &a-b&b \\1&0&0&\ldots &b-a&a \end{vmatrix}_{n\times n}$$
$$=(a+(n-1)b)(a-b)^{n-1}\begin{vmatrix} 1&0&0&0& \ldots&b\\1&1&0&0&\ldots&b\\1&0&1&0&\ldots&b \\ \vdots&0&0&1&\ldots &b \\ 1&0&0&\ldots &1&b \\1&0&0&\ldots &-1&a \end{vmatrix}_{n\times n}$$
I got stuck here. I can't find the way to solve this. However the answer is $(a+(n-1)b)(a-b)^{n-1}$.

your help will certainly be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: further add $(-b)$ of column-1 to column-n and proceed

Comment: please help me i am applying column operation not row operations so where am i wrong?

Comment: i want you to figure out my mistake. Can somebody help me